# Switch methods calls inside an executable

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly

I wonder how to switch the call to a function for another inside an executable (.exe in my case)

Here is the code I try to play with

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello()
{
    printf("Hello world!");
}

void investigate()
{
    printf("Investigate all the things!");
}

main()
{
    hello();
}
```

Once I compiled the above code (with gcc) and got an executable (.exe) out of it, I want to switch the "hello" call with "investigate".

--Edit--

My environment: Windows 10 (64bit), mingw with gcc/g++ 4.8.1

--Edit 2--

I'm fine with Linux answer (any Ubuntu or any OpenSuse and any architecture) too as for me it's very important to have a proof-of-concept.

Comment: No, there is no standard way to do this. Why do you need this? What problem are you _actually_ trying to resolve? You may consider using function pointers.

Comment: This is not possible in standard C without changing the code.  There are ways to do this, but I need to know the operating system and architecture you are programming for to give specific advice.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Any method will be a start for me. I need to alter the execution of an already built executable for whom I do not have sources. I use this simple example just to isolate the problem and to find a solution.

Comment: @Alex Then it's time to grab a tool like IDA-Pro or Radare and do some binary editing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the compiler is not omitting dead functions entirely, that it is not inlining the function and that the call won't go through the PLT, once you have compiled the executable, you can simply edit the call instruction.

Note that the two functions must be "compatible", where the notion of compatibility is fuzzy, it means "the new must satisfy at least the same assumptions the compiler made when calling the old one".
The ABI is of course one such assumption but it may not be the only one.

If your compiler omitted dead function, you can't switch the function (one is missing).

If your compiler inlined the call, you can't switch the function (there is no call). You can work against the compiler and rewrite the code at the call-site (in the C source), this is called patching.

If your compiler used the PLT, you need to change the GOT entry used by the PLT stub. You may need to document your self a bit but changing the linked procedure is actually a feature of PLT machinery.

If your compiler did nothing of that, this should be case for such a simple source when no optimisations are enabled, you can use `objdump -d <file>` to find the call-site and the address of the new function:

```
000000000040051d <hello>:
  40051d:   55                      push   %rbp
  40051e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400521:   bf f0 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005f0,%edi
  400526:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40052b:   e8 d0 fe ff ff          callq  400400 <printf@plt>
  400530:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400531:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400532 <investigate>:
  400532:   55                      push   %rbp
  400533:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400536:   bf fd 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005fd,%edi
  40053b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400540:   e8 bb fe ff ff          callq  400400 <printf@plt>
  400545:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400546:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400547 <main>:
  400547:   55                      push   %rbp
  400548:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40054b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400550:   e8 c8 ff ff ff          callq  40051d <hello>
  400555:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40055a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40055b:   c3                      retq   
  40055c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

Then change the immediate value of the `call` instruction with the difference between the target address and the address after the end of the `call` instruction (it doesn't matter where the origin is as long as it's the same for both addresses).

```
Target = 400532 
After the end of call = 400555
Difference = 400532 - 400555 = -23 = 0xFFFFFFDD

Change from:
400550: e8 c8 ff ff ff
to:
400550: e8 dd ff ff ff
```

Note that immediates are little-endiands.
You can use an hexeditor to edit the code, to find the offset into the file you can either use an elf reader and do a bit of math your self or you can simply search for the bytes of the call instruction (check also the bytes around the call to be sure).

After the edit, the binary has been patched:

```
 0000000000400532 <investigate>:
  400532:   55                      push   %rbp
  400533:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400536:   bf fd 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005fd,%edi
  40053b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400540:   e8 bb fe ff ff          callq  400400 <printf@plt>
  400545:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400546:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400547 <main>:
  400547:   55                      push   %rbp
  400548:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40054b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400550:   e8 dd ff ff ff          callq  400532 <investigate>
  400555:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40055a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40055b:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Note that OP is programming for Windows which doesn't have the notion of GOT and PLT tables.  You might want to adjust your examples to be relevant for that environment.

Comment: @fuz Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, the OP didn't specify their environment in the original post. I assumed Linux from the use of GCC. I'm not changing the answer at this point, they should have specified their env in the original question.

Comment: And that sort of thing is why I don't make assumptions anymore.  If the environment is insufficiently specified, I withhold my answer until clarification has been added.

Comment: Just updated the question to accept even Linux based solutions.

Comment: @Alex Are you also interested in solutions that work on ELF targets like Linux but not on PE targets like Windows?

Comment: @fuz Why not? Once I figured out on a platform it would be easier to replicate on a different one.

Comment: Because that method involves using a mechanism that only exists in this forn on ELF targets.  PE targets don't have it.

Comment: @Alex: to stop gcc from inlining and/or doing constant-propagation into private clones of a function, use `__attribute__((noinline,noclone))` on the function, so it might be possible to build a binary with suitable functions for this to work.